# Mat-button not display white as expected

Tags: angular

I created a mat-toolbar and added mat-buttons using

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

The font color for the mat-buttons stays gray instead of white

This is what it looks like
[image]
Here is the component.html code

```
<mat-toolbar-row>
     <div fxHide.gt-xs>   
       <button mat-button>     
        <mat-icon (click)="sidenav.toggle()">menu</mat-icon>
        menu 

      </button>
     </div> 
    <div class="icon-center" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxFlex >
       BuySell 
    </div>  

      <div fxFlex fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="flex-end" fxHide.xs>
        <button mat-button *ngIf="!signedIn" routerLink="/auth"><span  class="label"> Log in  </span></button>
        <button mat-button  *ngIf="!(path == '/home')" routerLink="/home"><span  class="label"> Home </span>
          </button>
        <button mat-button *ngIf="signedIn"  routerLink="/demo">
            <span class="label" > Demo </span>
        </button>  
        <button mat-button *ngIf="signedIn" color="accent"  routerLink="/stocks">
            <span class="label" > Stocks </span>
        </button>
        <button mat-button *ngIf="signedIn"  color="accent" routerLink="/">
            <span class="label" (click)="logOut()">Log Out</span>
        </button>
       </div>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
```

This is the component.ts

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
signedIn: boolean;
public path = '' ;
  @Output() public sidenavToggle = new EventEmitter();
  constructor( private amplifyService: AmplifyService, 
private router: Router) {
  this.amplifyService.authStateChange$
    .subscribe(authState => {
        this.signedIn = authState.state === 'signedIn';
   });
   this.path = router.url;
}
  public onToggleSidenav = () => {
    this.sidenavToggle.emit();
  }

}
```

Comment: Is it overwritten by the className `.label`? May I know what is declared within `.label`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the CSS properties of your `mat-button` are overwritten by the span with the class `.label`.

If there isn't anything important within it, you may want to remove the `.label` class entirely, or check if the `.label` class contains any CSS properties (such as `color`) that may have overwritten the default stylings for `mat-button`.

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>BuySell</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <button mat-button routerLink="/auth">
      <span>Log in</span>
    </button>
    <button mat-button routerLink="/stocks">
      Stocks
    </button>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

In addition, I notice that some of your buttons are styled with `accent` color. Do note that for those buttons, the text labels in the buttons will be red, instead of white.

Otherwise, your toolbar should work just fine, as shown in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxbmbd?file=app/toolbar-multirow-example.html).

Comment: I put accent color to show it is not affecting my mat-buttons. I guess I can try to do the project over. I cannot get the white text even though the sb works.

Answer (score 1):

You can override your mat button CSS with .label class CSS.
Change your CSS to this:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-button {
    color: #FFF !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use CSS to change it:

```
.mat-button {
    color: #FFF;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by adding css file.

```
/deep/ .mat-button {
    color: #FFF;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

You can get more idea for /deep/ by following [this link](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)